# Knit r markdown file that has displays specific list elements of list of gpplot objects

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, markdown

I want to knit r markdown file that has displays specific list elements of list of gpplot objects.

When I try to do so by using the "Run Selected line(s)" button using the code below, it DOES generate a plot within r markdown as a window in the r markdown code.

```
ggplot2:::print.ggplot(plot_object_name[["plot_element_name"]])
```

When I click into a current chuck and then hit the "Run Current Chunk" button using the code below, it DOES generate a plot within r markdown as a window in the r markdown code.

```
ggplot2:::print.ggplot(plot_object_name[["plot_element_name"]])
```

When I do this for all of the different elements of the list of ggplot objects and then run the code `rmarkdown::render("file_name.rmd")` in the r console, the r markdown file does not generate an HTML file and I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 97-99 (file_name.rmd) 
Error in dev.off() : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file 'file_name/figure-html/Chunk_label_unique_name-1.png'
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks ahead of time.